# Set field "DocumentDate" to PurchFormLetter

Tags: x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I am invoicing a purchase order using the PurchFormLetter:

```
 ttsbegin;

 purchTable = PurchTable::find(_deliveryHeader.PurchId, true);

 purchFormLetter = PurchFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice);

 purchFormLetter.update(purchTable, _deliveryHeader.InvoiceId, today(),PurchUpdate::ReceiveNow);

 ttscommit;
```

the invoice is done perfectly but in VendTrans, the DocumentDate field stays empty.

Comment: anyone knows, please?

Comment: Have you tried tracing the code? Perhaps a customization?